# Does calling Thread.interrupt() before a Thread.join() cause the join() to throw an InterruptedException immediately?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt, interrupted-exception

Basically, what the question title says.

```
Thread t = new Thread(someRunnable);
t.start();
t.interrupt();
t.join(); //does an InterruptedException get thrown immediately here?
```

From my own tests, it seems to, but just wanted to be sure. I'm guessing `Thread.join()` checks the `interrupted` status of the thread before doing its "wait" routine?

Comment: No, Thread.join() is only concerned with interruptions to the *current* thread.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`interrupt()` interrupts the thread you interrupted, not the thread doing the interrupting.

c.f.

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
t.join(); // will throw InterruptedException
```

Answer (score 26):

> Does calling Thread.interrupt() before a Thread.join() cause the join() to throw an InterruptedException immediately?

No it will not throw.  Only if the *current* thread that is calling the `join()` method gets interrupted will `join()` throw `InterruptedException`.  `t.interrupt()` is interrupting the thread you just started, while `t.join()` will only throw `InterruptedException` if the thread that is doing the join-ing (maybe the main thread?) is itself interrupted.

```
 Thread t = new Thread(someRunnable);
 t.start();
 t.interrupt();
 t.join();  // will _not_ throw unless this thread calling join gets interrupted
```

Also it is important to realize that interrupting a thread does not cancel it *and*  `join()` is not like a `Future` in that it will return the exception the thread threw.

When you interrupt a thread, any calls the thread is making to `sleep()`, `wait()`, `join()`, and other interruptible methods will throw `InterruptedException`.  If those methods are not called then the thread will continue running.  If a thread *does* throw a `InterruptedException` in response to being interrupted and then quits, that exception will be lost unless you you used `t.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler)`.

In your case, if the thread is interrupted and finishes because it returns, then the join will finish -- it will not throw an exception.  Common thread code to handle an interrupt properly is as follows:

```
 public void run() {
    try {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // a good pattern is to re-interrupt the thread when you catch
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       // another good pattern is to make sure that if you _are_ interrupted,
       // that you stop the thread
       return;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Upvote; but it may be confusing to say that re-interrupting the thread is "a good pattern."  If you've interrupted the flow of logic, isn't the original intent of the interrupt now fulfilled?  I would expand on this just a bit... return immediately; or clean up anything that needs cleaning and return immediately.  In any case "interrupt" is tricky; it's a dangerous language feature used in multiple ways by multiple parties...  a re-interrupt is probably only necessary if you're executing downstream code that will recognize that status.

Comment: It's always a good pattern @Robert because you don't know if your caller also needs to check the interrupt status of the thread.  reinterrupt may only be necessary in those cases but's always a good pattern because we tend to copy code around so bad patterns propagate.  I'm not the only one who thinks this.

Comment: My point is simple: without knowledge of what the caller is doing; there are scenarios in which re-interrupting is the right thing to do and scenarios in which it is the wrong thing to do.  In any case it's a good reminder to everyone: interrupt should not be taken for granted! -- and IMO avoided as a flow of control mechanism unless you know exactly how it will impact all upstream / downstream code.

Comment: It's a good pattern @Robert.  Like all patterns there are exceptions.  I encourage to do some more reading on the subject.  I'm not proposing anything radical here.

Comment: I know this subject well; no lack of understanding on my part here (but thank you for the encouragement).  Your post has a lot of good things in it--but the irony in your post and comments here is that you promote copy/paste of the code (which you also warn against) and say "it's a good pattern"; but you don't say why it is.  I am simply recommending that you defend that statement (or link to information on "the pattern").  Understanding *why* is important.  And in particular for a "pattern": *when* to follow that pattern is important.

Comment: Not sure I'm promoting copy&paste by showing a good pattern.  As to _when_, I'd say _always_ unless you have good reason not to.  This question wasn't about interrupts otherwise I would give an explanation.  Here's some good links: https://dzone.com/articles/why-do-we-need-threadcurrentthreadinterrupt-in-int https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2015/12/06/understanding-thread-interruption-in-java/  https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception   If there is any question as to my experience with this subject, check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multithreading/topusers

Answer (score 1):

`interrupt()` will interrupt the execution of referenced thread, if its affected by `sleep()` or `wait()` or `join()`.

1. As there is no sleep /join /wait called on the main, this would only update the `interrupted` flag.
2. Verifies statement 1
3. `t1.join()` pauses the execution of `MAIN thread` and allows t1 to execute before `MAIN thread` proceeds. But, it seems like main internally check `Thread.currentThread().isIntercepted()` and handles by raising the exception.
4. Verifies statement 3
5. Verifies statement 3 and also, as exception has raised `intercepted` flag is set back to false

**Sample Code:**

```
        t1.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" isInterrupted(): "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // -- 1
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" isInterrupted(): "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()); // -- 2
            t1.join(); // -- 3
            System.out.println("This is never called as exception is raised"); // -- 4
        }catch(InterruptedException ex){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" isInterrupted(): "+Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()); -- 5
        }
        System.out.println("Main continues");
```

**Output:**

```
main isInterrupted(): false
Thread-0: 0
main isInterrupted(): true
main isInterrupted(): false
Main continues
Thread-0: 1
Thread-0: 2
Thread-0: 3
```

Above call is from `main()`

I hope this would help understand better