# Terminate a thread by Thread name or ThreadGroup name - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

How do we terminate a `Thread` or `ThreadGroup` instance by it's name ?

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  SO is not your research assistent.

Comment: So us some effort that you had done to achieve this task..

Comment: In my case, I have dynamic numbers of threads running in the server. So I can't keep those references. When the response serves, all of thread hooks will be gone. And using a shared variable or volatile variable to give a signal won't work I think.

Comment: what makes you think that?

Comment: I can have those `Thread` references in my session. If so it will allocate some memory too. If I can use a `ThreadGroup`, and if I can stop all the threads under that `ThreadGroup` it will be much easier. But methods like stop(), suspend() etc are deprecated from the `ThreadGroup`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this

```
    Thread[] a = new Thread[1000];
    int n = Thread.enumerate(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i].getName().equals(name)) {
            a[i].interrupt();
            break;
        }
    }
```

though interrupt() does not terminate the thread, stop() does (though deprecated)

Comment: It's important to know that interrupting a thread does not "terminate" it.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632451/does-calling-thread-interrupt-before-a-thread-join-cause-the-join-to-throw/10635005#10635005

Comment: Interruption is the best approach, but executing code should support it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what do you mean when you say "terminate".

But first tip is that you have to get a list of all threads to terminate. Use `Thread.getThreads()` to do this. You can filter threads by their group if needed.

Now, how to stop the thread? There are 2 ways.

1. call `stop()` method. It is deprecated and you should never use it because it might cause system to enter inconsistent state. However, if you *really* want ... this method is still supported.
2. Every thread should support shutdown mechanism, i.e. a "protocol" that can be used to signal thread to exit its `run()` method. If all threads are yours you can make them to implement your own interface (e.g. `Terminatable`) with method `terminate()` that will change value of flag and cause thread to exit. In this case your code that terminates threads should iterate over threads, check that thread should be terminated and that it implements interface `Terminatable`, cast to it and call its `terminate()` method.