# What does this thread join code mean?

Tags: java, multithreading

In this code, what does the two joins and break mean? `t1.join()` causes `t2` to stop until `t1` terminates?

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1"));
t1.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(new EventThread("e2"));
t2.start();
while (true) {
   try {
      t1.join();
      t2.join();
      break;
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: Since it will block and wait for thread termination, why did you use the while loop ?

Comment: @MahdiElMasaoudi I suppose, to keep waiting even if the thread is interrupted? Probably not a great way of doing that

Comment: Remember to accept an answer here if it was helpful.

Comment: As mentioned, you don't need the `while(true)` to call the `join` method.

Answer (score 343):

> What does this thread join code mean?

To quote from the [`Thread.join()` method javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29):

> `join()` Waits for this thread to die.

There is a thread that is running your example code which is probably the [main thread](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/main-thread-java-t4178/).

1. The main thread creates and starts the `t1` and `t2` threads.  The two threads start running in parallel.
2. The main thread calls `t1.join()` to wait for the `t1` thread to finish.
3. The `t1` thread completes and the `t1.join()` method returns in the main thread.  Note that `t1` could already have finished before the `join()` call is made in which case the `join()` call will return immediately.
4. The main thread calls `t2.join()` to wait for the `t2` thread to finish.
5. The `t2` thread completes (or it might have completed before the `t1` thread did) and the `t2.join()` method returns in the main thread.

It is important to understand that the `t1` and `t2` threads have been running **in parallel** but the main thread that started them needs to wait for them to finish before it can continue.  That's a common pattern.  Also, `t1` and/or `t2` could have finished *before* the main thread calls `join()` on them.  If so then `join()` will not wait but will return immediately.

> `t1.join()` means cause t2 to stop until t1 terminates?

No.  The *main* thread that is calling `t1.join()` will stop running and wait for the `t1` thread to finish.  The `t2` thread is running in parallel and is not affected by `t1` or the `t1.join()` call at all.

In terms of the try/catch, the `join()` throws `InterruptedException` meaning that the main thread that is calling `join()` may itself be interrupted by another thread.

> ```
> while (true) {
> ```

Having the joins in a `while` loop is a strange pattern.  Typically you would do the first join and then the second join handling the `InterruptedException` appropriately in each case.  No need to put them in a loop.

Comment: +1 That's a very strange pattern and probably can be removed.

Comment: If t1 finish first, then t2 to finish. That seems to be a sequential process. One thread finishes first, then the other. what's the point of multiple threading?

Comment: Probably we can totally remove the while loop? what does the loop do? Only two threads which are listed already.

Comment: Because the `t1` and `t2` can run in parallel.  It's just that the `main` needs them both to finish before it can continue.  That's a typical pattern @user697911.

Comment: The `while` loop is there because (I guess) it wants to retry the `join()` calls if one is interrupted?  I certainly would not write it that way @user697911.

Comment: But main is the entry point of a Java program. It always starts first. I am confused. You mean t1.join() and t2.join() to cause main to suspend temporarily on the half way and then continue the main thread? what could happen if I get rid of the two joins?

Comment: Whatever thread that calls a `t1.join()` method will stop and wait until the `t1` thread finishes.  If main is the thread that is making the call then yes, the main thread will wait for `t1` to finish.  If you remove the `join()` calls then main will exit immediately and the `t1` and `t2` threads will continue running in the background.  If `t1` and `t2` are daemon threads then if the main thread finishes the JVM will finish.

Comment: The loop is there to ensure that both `t1` and `t2` finish. Ie. if `t1` throws the `InterruptedException`, it will loop back and wait for `t2`. An alternative is to wait for both threads in each their Try-Catch, so the loop can be avoided. Also, depending on `EventThread`, it can make sense to do it this way, as we're running 2 threads, not one.

Comment: THe `InterruptedException` is if the thread that is calling `join()` is interrupted, not either `t1` or `t2` @MichaelBisbjerg.  If the calling thread is interrupted, it most likely should exit and not call `join()` again.  But that depends on why it is interrupted.

Comment: @Gray, ah, I see. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632451/does-calling-thread-interrupt-before-a-thread-join-cause-the-join-to-throw

Comment: Want to emphasis on very important thing mentioned here :-  "the main thread that is calling t1.join() will stop running and wait for the t1 thread to finish." Another important point is "The t2 thread is running in parallel and is not affected by t1."

Comment: Definition of join:  "to bring in contact, connect, or bring or put together".  Sounds about right to me @MelAdane. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/join?s=t

Comment: I still think `join` is not a good term. Better name? `waitUntilFinished()`.

Answer (score 77):

This is a **favorite Java interview** question.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1"));
t1.start();
Thread e2 = new Thread(new EventThread("e2"));
t2.start();

while (true) {
    try {
        t1.join(); // 1
        t2.join(); // 2  These lines (1,2) are in in public static void main
        break;
    }
}
```

`t1.join()` means, t1 says something like "**I want to finish first**". Same is the case with `t2`. No matter who started `t1` or `t2` thread (in this case the `main` method), main will wait until `t1` and `t2` finish their task.

However, an important point to note down, `t1` and `t2` themselves **can run in parallel irrespective of the join call sequence**  on `t1` and `t2`. It is the `main/daemon` thread that has to **wait**.

Comment: Good example. About " can run in parallel": So what? It is important that the main thread will wait FIRST for t1 and THEN for t2. It really does not matter what t1 or t2 are doing (from the main thread perspective)

Comment: You mention the "main/daemon" thread.  The main I understand but the daemon has nothing to do with it.  The main thread is non-daemon.

Comment: `t1.join(); t2.join();` will not allow the thread that executes the joins to continue until both threads have terminated. In the absence of very unusual code elsewhere, the order of the joins does not matter.

Comment: So will t2.join() be called only when t1 finished?

Comment: In other words, if we want to "serialize" execution of t1 and t2 threads, we need to place t1.join() right after t1.start() since main thread started t1 (and t2 afterwards) and of course remove it from try/catch.
Obviously, doing so, the consequence will be a loss of parallelism.

Answer (score 53):

`join()` means waiting for a thread to complete. This is a blocker method. Your main thread (the one that does the `join()`) will wait on the `t1.join()` line until `t1` finishes its work, and then will do the same for `t2.join()`.

Answer (score 47):

A picture is worth a thousand words.

```
    Main thread-->----->--->-->--block##########continue--->---->
                 \                 |               |
sub thread start()\                | join()        |
                   \               |               |
                    ---sub thread----->--->--->--finish
```

Hope to useful, for more detail click [here](http://www.henryxi.com/java-thread-join-example)

Comment: Clear and precise.

Comment: Is the thread that calls `join()` in BLOCKED state or is it WAITING?

Comment: When a thread is blocked waiting for a monitor, its state is `BLOCKED`. When a thread is waiting for another thread, its state is `WAITING`. for more detail click my other blog. [java thread state](http://www.henryxi.com/java-thread-state-example)

Comment: Didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

When thread tA call tB.join() its causes not only waits for tB to die or tA be interrupted itself but create happens-before relation between last statement in tB and next statement after tB.join() in tA thread.

> [All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

It means program

```
class App {
    // shared, not synchronized variable = bad practice
    static int sharedVar = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread threadB = new Thread(() -> {sharedVar = 1;});
        threadB.start();
        threadB.join();

        while (true) 
            System.out.print(sharedVar);
    }
}
```

Always print

```
>> 1111111111111111111111111 ...
```

But program

```
class App {
    // shared, not synchronized variable = bad practice
    static int sharedVar = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread threadB = new Thread(() -> {sharedVar = 1;});
        threadB.start();
        // threadB.join();  COMMENT JOIN

        while (true)
            System.out.print(sharedVar);
    }
}
```

Can print not only

```
>> 0000000000 ... 000000111111111111111111111111 ...
```

But

```
>> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ...
```

Always only '0'.

Because Java Memory Model don't require 'transfering' new value of 'sharedVar' from threadB to main thread without heppens-before relation (thread start, thread join, usage of 'synchonized' keyword, usage of AtomicXXX variables, etc).

Answer (score 6):

Simply put: 
`t1.join()` returns after `t1` is completed.
  It doesn't do anything to thread `t1`, except wait for it to finish.
Naturally, code following 
`t1.join()` will be executed only after 
`t1.join()` returns.

Comment: will be executed only after  t1.join() returns  +1

Answer (score 4):

From oracle documentation [page on Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> The `join` method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another.

If t1 is a `Thread` object whose thread is currently executing,

```
t1.join() : causes the current thread to pause execution until t1's thread terminates.
```

If t2 is a `Thread` object whose thread is currently executing,

```
t2.join(); causes the current thread to pause execution until t2's thread terminates.
```

`join` API is low level API, which has been introduced in earlier versions of java. Lot of things have been changed over a period of time (especially with jdk 1.5 release) on concurrency front.

You can achieve the same with java.util.concurrent API. Some of the examples are

1. Using [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) on `ExecutorService`
2. Using [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)
3. Using [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) or [newWorkStealingPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--) of `Executors`(since java 8)

Refer to related SE questions:

[wait until all threads finish their work in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939257/wait-until-all-threads-finish-their-work-in-java/36797569#36797569)

Answer (score 3):

For me, Join() behavior was always  confusing because I was trying to remember who will wait for whom.
Don't try to remember it that way.

> Underneath, it is pure wait() and notify() mechanism.

We all know that, when we call wait() on any object(t1), calling object(main) is sent to waiting room(Blocked state).

Here, main thread is calling join() which is wait() under the covers. So main thread will wait until it is notified. 
Notification is given by t1 when it finishes it's run(thread completion).

After receiving the notification, main comes out of waiting room and proceeds it's execution.

Comment: hmm, does this mean i can think of it as javascript's `await` function? Haha

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

```
package join;

public class ThreadJoinApp {

    Thread th = new Thread("Thread 1") {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Current thread execution - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Current thread execution - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at index - " + i);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread th2 = new Thread("Thread 2") {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Current thread execution - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            //Thread 2 waits until the thread 1 successfully completes.
            try {
            th.join();
            } catch( InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception has been caught");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Current thread execution - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " at index - " + i);
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadJoinApp threadJoinApp = new ThreadJoinApp();
        threadJoinApp.th.start();
        threadJoinApp.th2.start();
    }

    //Happy coding -- Parthasarathy S
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The join() method is used to hold the execution of currently running thread until the specified thread is dead(finished execution).

**Why we use join() method?**

In normal circumstances we generally have more than one thread, thread scheduler schedules the threads, which does not guarantee the order of execution of threads.

Let's take a look at an example, create new project and copy the following code:

this is activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_without_join"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Start Threads Without Join"/>
 <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/btn_with_join"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_without_join"
     android:text="Start Threads With Join"/>
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/tv"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_with_join"
     />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is code for MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
volatile  String threadName = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Button btn_without_join = findViewById(R.id.btn_without_join);
    btn_without_join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            withoutJoin();
        }
    });
    Button btn_with_join = findViewById(R.id.btn_with_join);
    btn_with_join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            withJoin();
        }
    });
}
private void withoutJoin()
{
    tv.setText("");
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th1");
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th2");
    Thread th3 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th3");
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
}
private void withJoin()
{
    tv.setText("");
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th1");
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th2");
    Thread th3 = new Thread(new MyClass2(), "th3");
    th1.start();
    try {
        th1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    th2.start();
    try {
        th2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    th3.start();
}
class MyClass2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Thread started: "+t.getName());
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Thread ended: "+t.getName());
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

This will be the result if you press first button (Start Threads Without Join):
[image]

And this will be the result if you press second button (Start Threads With Join):
[image]

Answer (score -3):

let's say our main thread starts the threads t1 and t2. Now, when t1.join() is called, the main thread suspends itself till thread t1 dies and then resumes itself.
Similarly, when t2.join() executes, the main thread suspends itself again till the thread t2 dies and then resumes.

So, this is how it works.

Also, the while loop was not really needed here.