# Thread program confusion over join

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through oracle tutorials on Threads.I found below program a bit confusing.According to me join  method is used for a thread to wait until current thread finishes execution.Why are they calling t.join(1000) , is this to make  main thread wait ?
why they have to t.join after calling t.interrupt()

```
public class SimpleThreads {

    // Display a message, preceded by
    // the name of the current thread
    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName =
            Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                          threadName,
                          message);
    }

    private static class MessageLoop
        implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            String importantInfo[] = {
                "Mares eat oats",
                "Does eat oats",
                "Little lambs eat ivy",
                "A kid will eat ivy too"
            };
            try {
                for (int i = 0;
                     i < importantInfo.length;
                     i++) {
                    // Pause for 4 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    // Print a message
                    threadMessage(importantInfo[i]);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                threadMessage("I wasn't done!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {

        // Delay, in milliseconds before
        // we interrupt MessageLoop
        // thread (default one hour).
        long patience = 1000 * 60 * 60;

        // If command line argument
        // present, gives patience
        // in seconds.
        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                patience = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1000;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Argument must be an integer.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        threadMessage("Starting MessageLoop thread");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
        t.start();

        threadMessage("Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish");
        // loop until MessageLoop
        // thread exits
        while (t.isAlive()) {
            threadMessage("Still waiting...");
            // Wait maximum of 1 second
            // for MessageLoop thread
            // to finish.
            t.join(1000);
            if (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) > patience)
                  && t.isAlive()) {
                threadMessage("Tired of waiting!");
                t.interrupt();
                // Shouldn't be long now
                // -- wait indefinitely
                t.join();
            }
        }
        threadMessage("Finally!");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you interrupt a threat, it isn't necessarily exited. So you add a join just to make sure that  while (t.isAlive()) will be FALSE and you can exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

They are calling interrupt to stop the current function the thread is processing and then join to tell the thread to wait.

You might find this post helpful

[What does this thread join code mean? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956231/what-does-this-thread-join-code-mean)

and the following articles on concurrency

[Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

[Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)