# Terminating a thread from a callback function in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, callback

I am using an API that communicates with video camera devices.  My aim is to take a snapshot with the device.

The API works with callbacks.  You connect a callback function to the functionality you want.  In this case, taking snapshots.

The functions for doing so look something like this...

```cpp
MEDIALIB_SETSNAPCB(this, snapcb); // connect snapshot callback to callback function snapcb
MEDIALIB_TAKESNAP(device_nr, channel); // take snapshot of specified channel
```

The problem is that I need to wait for the callback function `snapcb` to respond before exiting the program.  `snapcb` may take up to 50 seconds to respond after running `MEDIALIB_TAKESNAP`, which does not wait for the callback to complete before going to the next line.

Here is a stripped down version:

```cpp
...
int Snapshot::takeSnap()
{
    MEDIALIB_SETSNAPCB(this, snapcb); // connect snapshot callback to callback function snapcb

    CString device_nr = "TC1234";
    int channel = 1;
    MEDIALIB_TAKESNAP(device_nr, channel); // take snapshot of specified channel
    return 0;
}

void Snapshot::snapcb(const char* device_nr, int channel, const char* pBuf, int nLen, void* pUsr)
{
    Snapshot* pThis = (Snapshot*)pUsr;
    pThis->snapdatacb(device_nr, channel, pBuf, nLen);
}

void Snapshot::snapdatacb(const char* device_nr, int channel, const char* pBuf, int nLen)
{
    // ... create file on computer ...
}
...
```

I have thought of running `MEDIALIB_TAKESNAP(device_nr, channel);` in a thread and then firing a conditional variable for when the callback returns, but have been unable to find a example of how to use a conditional variable in this situation.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Also, please comment on how I structured my question as I am still learning how to ask a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire a new thread t1 then call t1.join().
Set t1 function to return when the callback is done.

[What does this thread join code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956231/what-does-this-thread-join-code-mean)