# How to delete Thread object from an array?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

The program I am creating requires an array of thread objects. More specifically I have a class which extends Thread. I am doing this so that each new object created runs on its own thread. If I want to kill the thread and remove it from the array element, so that I can create a new Thread object in that space, how do I do this? This is my thought.

I understand that removing reference to the thread will not actually stop the thread. To do this I would first need to interrupt the thread. To remove the thread object from the array, can I simply make it null? I.e.:

```
array[i].interrupt();    
array[i] = null;
```

And then I would be able to create a new thread in that space?

```
array[i] = new Thread();
```

Assume that the run method of the Thread objects handles interruptions properly etc.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying? Interrupting is not the same as stopping though.

Comment: This should work, but to ensure the thread is stopped before you create a new one, you can do array[i].join() before setting the element to null.

Comment: Can you share your requirements, why do you need an array of thread objects ?

Comment: @MauricePerry The OP would be calling `interrupt` on the `Thread` .

Comment: @CKing yes.....

Comment: @MauricePerry What's the point of calling `join` on a thread that has been interrupted?

Comment: @CKing to make sure it's terminated. A thread can catch the InterruptedException

Comment: @CKing it still does IMHO.

Comment: @MauricePerry Do read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632451/does-calling-thread-interrupt-before-a-thread-join-cause-the-join-to-throw)

Comment: There is no reason to assign `null` to an array slot if the next thing you do is assign a new Thread reference to the same slot.

Comment: @jameslarge Exactly (as already mentioned in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

> To remove the thread object from the array, can I simply make it null

Yes. This should make the reference held at index position `i` to point to `null`. However, if you are setting the element at index position `i` to `null` and then immediately saying `array[i] = new Thread();`, you can skip the step where you set it to `null` and only use `array[i] = new Thread();` instead.

Also note that just adding the element to the array won't start the newly inserted `Thread`. You would still need to call `array[i].start()` after inserting the new `Thread` in the array to start the new `Thread`.

That said, extending from `Thread` makes sense only if you plan to override some of the functionalities from the `Thread` class. (I personally don't see any valid use case for this). You should instead implement `Runnable` and pass it to the `Thread` constructor.